# Java custom validation annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

```
    public class Student{
    @NotNull
    private Course course= null;

    @CustomValidation(enumCourse = course)
    private String details = null;
    }
}
```

How can i pass the course variable to CustomValidation annotation? Im getting an error saying that course must be an enum constant expression.

I have written a  custom validation interface and validator too.

Answer (score 2):

Annotation property must be constant at compile time.

You cannot use variable there.

The keyword here is `cross fields validation`.

You have two option:

1. Create annotation at class level. There you have access to all properties of class and validation should be done easy
2. Or create annotation at method level which return all necessary fields for validations.

   ```
   @CustomAnnotations
   Pair<Course, String> getCourseAndDetailForValidation() {
      return Pair.of(course, details)
   }
   ```

   You can change return type to match your taste, it may be a List, an Array, wrapper objects...

Comment: How do i pass this method to  @CustomValidation(enumCourse = course) ?

Comment: Did you read about custom validation? Once you annotated your method with `@CustomAnnotation`, in your `CustomAnnotationValidator.java` class, you have access those properties (`course` and `details`) inside `isValid()` method, and you can implement your logic there

Answer (score 0):

It's specified by section 9.6.1 of the JLS. The annotation member types must be one of:

primitive
String
Class
an Enum
another Annotation
an array of any of the above

Course must be one of those types.